# Help Understanding Proof about Dimension Theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I am reading through Atiyah and Macdonald's Dimension theory, chapter, but I can't understand a step in the proof. The relevant definitions are included below. $\lambda$ is hte length function.

[image]

Why do we get $g(t)$ above? Where does this come from? If we have an exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow K[k_s] \rightarrow M[k_s] \rightarrow M \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0 $$
of graded modules, then shouldn't we get
$$ t^{k_s} \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \lambda(N_i)t^i - t^{k_s} \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \lambda(M_i)t^i + \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \lambda(M_i)t^i - \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \lambda(L_i)t^i = 0 $$
I get no polynomial $g(t)$ as far as I can understand, since It seems like $M_i \cong L_i$ for $0 \leq i < k_s$ anyways.

---

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, since this is speculation and not anything authoritative on the matter: I think you have the right of the matter. To elaborate, I agree with everything you've written, and I think the discrepancy between your approach and AM's is in the definition of $L$. If I understand you correctly, you define $L$ (as I would) as the cokernel of the multiplication by $x_{s}$ on $M$, and then observe that it has a graded $A$-module structure such that $L_{i} \cong M_{i}$ for $0 \leqslant i < k_{s}$, and $L_{n+k_{s}}$ fits into the described exact sequence for all $n \geqslant 0$. Continued...

Comment: On the other hand, I think AM define $L_{n+k_{s}}$ for all $n \geqslant 0$ as the cokernel of ($A_{0}$-linear) multiplication by $x_{s}$ from $M_{n} \to M_{n+k_{s}}$. This leaves the definition of $L_{i}$ ambiguous for $0 \leqslant i < k_{s}$, and there are many ways to define $L_{i}$ for $0 \leqslant i < k_{s}$ such that $L = \oplus_{i} L_{i}$ is a graded $A$-module. Indeed, one such way is to take $L_{i} = 0$ for $0 \leqslant i < k_{s}$; then $L_{n+k_{s}}$ still fits into the prescribed exact sequence for every $n \geqslant 0$, and so the proof goes through as described, only instead of...

Comment: $g(t) = 0$, you would have $g(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{k_{s}-1} \lambda(M_{i})t^{i}$. Of course, we still get the same power series description of $P(M, t)$, since changing $L$ in this way changes $P(L, t)$ accordingly! As noted above, I prefer your way of doing things.

Comment: Oh, that makes great sense, @AlexWertheim! So they just didn't choose to define $L = \oplus_i L_i$ as the cokernel, and $g(t)$ plus "their" $L$ is "my" $L$. I like your answer- you should convert these comments into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think so! I can't really see why they chose to describe its graded pieces and then take direct sums rather than just observing that $L = \mathrm{coker}( \cdot x_{s})$ has the desired graded structure, but maybe I am underselling the subtlety of the latter approach somehow.

Comment: If I remember well this proof contains an error which I pointed out some time ago on an Errata thread opened on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying $t^{n+k_s}$, $t^{n+k_s}λ(K_n)-t^{n+k_s}λ(M_n)+t^{n+k_s}λ(M_{n+k_s})-t^{n+k_s}λ(L_{n+k_s})=t^{k_s}t^{n}λ(K_n)-t^{k_s}t^{n}λ(M_n)+t^{n+k_s}λ(M_{n+k_s})-t^{n+k_s}λ(L_{n+k_s})$.

Summing with respect to $n$, $t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(K_n)-t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n+k_s}λ(M_{n+k_s})-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n+k_s}λ(L_{n+k_s})$

$=t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(K_n)-t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)+(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n+k_s}λ(M_{n+k_s})+\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(M_{n})-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(M_{n}))-(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n+k_s}λ(L_{n+k_s})+\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(L_{n})-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(L_{n}))$

$=t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(K_n)-t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)+(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(M_{n}))-(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(L_n)-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(L_{n}))=0$

From the last equality, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)-t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(M_n)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(L_n)-t^{k_s}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} t^{n}λ(K_n)+(\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(M_{n})-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(L_{n})$.

By taking $g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(M_{n})-\sum_{n=0}^{k_{s}-1} t^{n}λ(L_{n})$,

$(1-t^{k_s})P(M,t)=P(L,t)-t^{k_s}P(K,t)+g(t)$.